# Python help - read from txt file and find a numerical series

Tags: python, text

I have a text file that I have to read from numbers(17 numbers in a row) and from this find the 3 most common numerical series(7 numbers) that appear
my approach to this was to make a list for every line(3883 lines) and sort them but I have no clue how to check for the series.
Thank you very much for all of you trying

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: I just don't know what am I doing so it is best not to show

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a `.txt` file this way:

```
with open("myFile.txt", 'r') as file: # Opening the file in read (r) mode
    content = file.read()
```

If you're trying to check a table with numerical values you may need to use the Python's module `pandas`.
If your numbers are separated by commas, you need to use the Python's module `csv` to read the `.txt` file as a `.csv` (Comma Separated Values) file.